# Dynamically generated webpage scraping

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, screen-scraping

I'm trying to build a parser which can download a data from web page. The problem is that the page is probably "dynamically generated". There is some code in curly brackets which generates html code probably. It seems like Django code.

Here is a pattern:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript">var browseDefaultColumn = 4; var browse5ColumnLength= '15,24'; var browse4ColumnLength = '20,28'; var browse3ColumnLength = '25,42';var priceFilterSliderEnabled = true;var browseLowPageLength = 24;var browseHighPageLength = 100;</script>
<script id="products-template" type="text/template">
    {{#products}}
        <li class="{{RowCssClass}}" style="{{RowStyle}}" li-productid="{{ItemCode}}">
            <div class="s-productthumbbox">
                <div class="productimage s-productthumbimage col-xs-6 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <a href="{{PrdUrl}}" class="s-product-sache">{{#ImgSashVisible}}
                            <img src="{{ImgSashUrl}}" class="rtSashImg img-responsive">
                        {{/ImgSashVisible}}
                    </a>
                    <a href="{{PrdUrl}}" class="ProductImageList">
                        <div>
                            <img class="rtimg img-responsive" src='{{MainImage}}' alt='{{Brand}} {{DisplayName}}' />
                        </div>
                        {{#EnableAltImages}}
                            <div class="AlternateImageContainerDiv">
                                <img class="rtimg ProductImageListAlternateImage img-responsive" src='{{AltImage}}' alt='{{Brand}} {{DisplayName}}' />
                            </div>
                        {{/EnableAltImages}}
                    </a>
                    <div class="QuickBuyAndWishListContainerDiv hidden-xs {{QuickBuyAndWishListCss}}">
                        {{#IsQuickBuyEnabled}}
```

I'm looking for a way how to get the whole code containing generated code so I can parse it for example using Beautiful Soup. Or other efficient way to get the data.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML you have is probably a template, and it needs to be parsed by a template engine to populate the content, after which you should be able to get the final HTML and parse that.
You do not normally get template HTML server from a server, this must be an offline file?